# How to set ‘in' attribute in ' pack' method (tkinter library)?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
Button(window,text='').pack(in=?)
```

How to set 'in' attribute in pack method? what does that mean?
I looked at the source code of the pack, but I still couldn't understand how to set the ’in' attribute about pack method.
[image]

Comment: I don't believe you can have a parameter named `in`, as that is a reserved word.

Comment: you can look at the soure code about pack , it has that attribute

Comment: You have to spell it as `in_` when specifying this option via a keyword parameter.  Notice the very next line of the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set 'in' attribute in pack method?

You must use `in_` rather than `in`. For example:

```
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
button = tk.Button(root)
button.pack(in_=frame)
```

> what does that mean?

When laying out a widget, every widget except the root window has a master -- some other widget which contains the widget and which controls how it is laid out.  By default the master is the same as the parent. For example, if you do `Button(window,text='')`, the parent of the button is `window`, and thus its master will also default to `window`.

You can use `in_` to change the master. For example, you could make a button be the child of the root window, but be laid out in some other frame. In the earlier example, the button is a child of the root window but will be a slave inside of the frame.

This is something you almost never need to do with tkinter, since it's usually preferable to have the parent and the master be the same widget.